# javascript replace fails to work with "<"

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I am trying to replace `"<"` and `">"` in a string using javascript's replace function. I am using it as follows:

```html
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<p id="demo">#include <iostream></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/</g, '&lt; ').replace(/>/g, '&gt; ');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to be `"#include <iostream>"`, but a corresponding `</iostream>` is appended to the desired output.

What is going on? How do I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Did you escape <iostream> in the html? If you didn't, replace '<' with &lt; and '>' with &gt;. If you don't escape the text, the browser treats <iostream> as a tag, and closes it appropriately.

Comment: It is being interpreted as _HTML_, `<iostream>` tag is opened but not closed, then the `<p>` is closed, making the interpreter insert a close tag for `<iostream>`.

Comment: Have you tried valid HTML in the first place?

Comment: I just want to automate the replacement of "<" and ">" with &lt; and &gt; respectively. @rioc0719: I don't want to do manual replacement.

Comment: @asmeltseg Let me tell you, JS is not the right way to go about that.

Comment: @PaulS.: How do I prevent that? Any other way to automate the replacement process?

Comment: @asmeltseg this replacement should be done server-side before the user sees anything

Comment: @TheWobbuffet: Too late! I am using google-code-prettify, which is in JS :( It is eating up my "<iostream>", and one way to avoid that would be to replace it by "&lt; iostream &gt;".

Comment: @asmeltseg: It's not too late to fix your actual problem. Don't try a clientside hack that apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `<iostream>` in your html, it is being interpreted as a tag in your browser which adds an extra closing `</iostream>`. It looks as if you're trying to escape it using JS, but it's too late because your browser is loading the html before the javascript, adding the extra closing tag. Escape it in your html to avoid the extra closing tag being appended behavior:

```
<p id="demo">#include &lt;iostream&gt;</p>
```

> I just want to automate the replacement of "<" and ">" with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. @rioc0719: I don't want to do manual replacement.`

*Please* don't try to do this with JS. Get an IDE that does it for you. Hell, make a server-side script that does this for you; just *don't use JS,  a client-side language,* for this.

Answer (score 0):

2 answer in question

- autoclose tag with "innerHTML" : found [Javascript - .innerHTML changes auto close tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728671/javascript-innerhtml-changes-auto-close-tags)
- replace "<" and ">" use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

```html
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<p id="demo">#include <iostream> </p>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/</g, '&lt; ').replace(/>/g, '&gt; ');
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent  = res;
}
 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```