# Form button add dynamically in JS

Tags: javascript, forms, button, listener

I tried to add dynamically a form in JavaScript, but when I click on the submit button nothing happens. I know that is because the button has no listener, but I don't know what I have to add in the listener for a normal sending button behavior.

Here some of my code

```
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "<form id='download_report' method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form' action='include/client.process.php'>";
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='jobid' value='" + jobId + "'/>";
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='job' value='" + job_details.heavyInfosJson + "'/>";
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='download_report' value='1'/>";
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "<button id='download_report_button' type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>T&eacute;l&eacute;charger le rapport</button>";
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "</form>";
```

I want from the listener to juste send the form to my `client.process.php`

I know that it s a beginner question but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/9/)**.

You should add the inputs inside `form` and not inside div `partTwo`, so your code should be like :

```
document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "<form id='download_report' method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form' action='include/client.process.php'>";
document.getElementById("download_report").innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='jobid' value='" + jobId + "'/>";
document.getElementById("download_report").innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='job' value='" + job_details.heavyInfosJson + "'/>";
document.getElementById("download_report").innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='download_report' value='1'/>";
document.getElementById("download_report").innerHTML += "<button id='download_report_button' type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>T&eacute;l&eacute;charger le rapport</button>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, i understand but are you sure for the last element ?
it would be document.getElementById("partTwo").innerHTML += "</form>"; no ?

Comment: No champ, the form is autoclosed.

Comment: So if I underwent well, i don't need to add listener on button ? The button behavior is correct even if it is created dynamically ?

Comment: Yes that true the `type='submit'` in button tell him that it should submit the  parent form.

Comment: Be advised button with type sybmit will cause page reloading. if you dont want page reloadint - like in SPA, you need use button listeners.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<form>` tag is autoclosed. `innerHTML` returns well formed html.  See  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728671/javascript-innerhtml-changes-auto-close-tags)

Comment: That a point, but actually the problem is appending the whole tags in the same level when the inputs should be inside the form, check my answer please.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki i agree with you. I have provided cause and you have provided solution. Perfect job! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `createElement` rather than `innerHTML`, see [2946656](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml)

Here is a basic example of how to create a form and append it to the page:

```js
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('action', 'contact.php');
form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');

var inputField = document.createElement("input");
inputField.setAttribute('value', 'example');
form.appendChild(inputField);

document.body.appendChild(form);
```